# trigger option not performing ajax calls in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am selecting an option when a page is being loaded. the option gets selected but the ajax request responsible for the select option doesn't get called.. anybody know how to get rid of the problem.? 
thanks in advance
here is my code below...

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#allowance_id').val(2).click()


  $(document).on('change', '#allowance_id', function(){
     ajax: {
        //some ajax work
     },

});


    })
```

the ajax perform normally works when i change the option by myself but not working with trigger

Answer (score 1):

Try using `trigger` like this.
`$('#allowance_id').val(2).trigger('change');`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '#allowance_id', function(e) {
    console.log('make ajax call')
  });
  
  $('#allowance_id').val(2).trigger('change');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="allowance_id">Choose a car:</label>

<select id="allowance_id">
  <option value="0">Volvo</option>
  <option value="1">Saab</option>
  <option value="2">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="3">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i tried using this before, but ddin't work. the value get changed but the ajax call doesnt get performed

Comment: can you post a working snippet so that we can try to help

Comment: @AbidusSattarAziz updated code snippet. can you try that once?

Comment: yes it worked.. so its just the matter of putting the trigger after the call.?

Comment: yes. you would have to define the event before triggering it.